# client bases authentication via certificate signed by ROOT CA

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have generated a ROOT CA and can successfully use it for client based authentication:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -subj "$SUBJECT"  -days 3650 -keyout root_ca.key -out root_ca.crt
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -subj "$SUBJECT2" -out client.csr -keyout client.key 
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in client.csr -CA root_ca.crt -CAkey root_ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 730
openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12 -passout pass:
```

(in $SUBJECT2 the CN is different)

In webserver (apache):

```
  SSLVerifyClient on
  SSLCACertificateFile conf/root_ca.crt
```

`root_ca.crt` imported as authority and `client.p12` as personal certificate in the browser (firefox, chromium)

Now I have created an intermediate CA:

```
openssl req  -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -subj "$SUBJECT" -keyout intermediateCA.key -out intermediateCA.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in intermediateCA.csr -CA root_ca.crt -CAkey root_ca.key -CAcreateserial -out intermediateCA.crt -days 1095
```

and use it (`intermediateCA.crt`) in the webserver instead of the `root_ca.crt`.

Unfortunately the web-browser (and webserver) are reporting errors when trying to access the website using `client.p12`.

P.S.:
Later I want to use client certificates sign by the intermediate CA for certain users. Using `client_intermediate.p12` one should be able to access only the web-side with the `intermediateCA.crt` while other users using only `client.p12` should be able to access websites using `intermediateCA.crt` and websites using `root_ca.crt`.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -subj "$SUBJECT" -out client_intermediate.csr -keyout client_intermediate.key 
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in client_intermediate.csr -CA intermediateCA.crt -CAkey intermediateCA.key -CAcreateserial -out client_intermediate.crt -days 730
openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -in client_intermediate.crt -inkey client_client_intermediate.key -out client_intermediate.p12 -passout pass:
```

Comment: If the value of `$SUBJECT` is the same for your intended intermediate cert as your root, and at least basicconstraints extension not added, it isn't actually an intermediate. If it is, OpenSSL by default (or below 1.1.0) won't treat it as an 'anchor' thus neither will Apache (httpd). And if a client (leaf) cert has the same subject as its CA, that won't work either. Finally, this isn't about programming or development, and thus is offtopic; try superuser and be clearer (and consistent, you mix 'intermediate' and 'deichmann').

Comment: Changing the `CN` in the Intermediate CA did not help. I have corrected and adapted the description and switched to superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1663379/client-bases-authentication-via-certificate-signed-by-root-ca